Hangfire not working with postgreSQL with .net core api with graphQL
I am using hangfire to execute a method in recurring, I am working on .net core API with graphQL using PostgreSQL 15.
When I run the project and open the hangfire dashboard, it's open as it should be, but when I open the jobs tab, it shows the below error.
Please help me with the solution!

